# having issue in get disk space value in powershell

Tags: powershell

I used to get disk space value by the following code, but when I pass this value to text box it shows some message

```ps1
$val = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
        Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
                Select-Object DeviceID, Description,`
            @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
                    @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}} |
        FT -AutoSize
```

Result is my text box name

```
$result.Text+= $val
```

Also, I want to show if free disk space is less then `1 gb` then it shows a warning message on my text box so what should I do?

Also, I want to get the exchange services  which is running or not

```
$outputBox.Text+= Get-Service | Where {$_.DisplayName -Like "Microsoft Exchange*"} | select-object name ,status
```

but doesn't show any thing  into textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ft is short for format-table which is more often than not just formatting for the console so it looks pretty to the user, but it breaks the powershell object. try removing that if you are assigning it to a variable. also, if you only want the free space, try this, though it may need adjusting depending on what you are trying to get out of this

```
$result.Text += (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} | % {$_.deviceid + ' ' + ('{0:N}' -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float])}) -join '; '

$ouputBox.text += (Get-Service | Where {$_.DisplayName -Like "Microsoft Exchange*"} | % {$_.name + ' ' + $_.status}) -join '; '
```

Comment: thanks it works for me but if i want to print each exchange services into a new line then what should i do??

Comment: $outputBox.Text +=(Get-Service | Where {$_.DisplayName -Like "Microsoft Exchange*"} | % {$_.name + ' :' + $_.status}) -join '; ' -split ';' I am using his but not working

Comment: You could -join with "`n" instead of '; '